# Marketing Cloud - Opening a link when user clicks on the image of an In-app message

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way to open open a link by clicking on the IMAGE of the In-app message? We would not like to use buttons.

In the picture below, the **red area** is the image I used in the message, and the **gray area** is the background of my application. I want to redirect the user to a web page when he clicks on the red area (image).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much do you want to experiment? :)

So, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777812/617044 shows a way to override an XML layout.

`mcsdk_iam_fif_e2e_itb.xml` is the ImageTitleBody FullImageFill Edge2Edge layout you're probably using.

Override the layout, make the `ImageView` clickable and/or make your own `View` that extends `ImageView` ... assign a click listener when the view is drawn and handle the click.

There's a whole lot of hand-wavy stuff in this "answer". Outside of any of this experiment working, there is no way currently to do what you're asking.

Here's the view for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/mcsdk_iam_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/mcsdk_iam_fs_content_inset"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/mcsdk_iam_close"
        style="@style/McSdk.FullImageFill.CloseBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/mcsdk_iam_close_btn"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mcsdk_content_description_close_button"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:translationZ="1dp"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/mcsdk_iam_media"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mcsdk_content_description_image"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mcsdk_iam_space"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="#21A0DF"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        />

    <Space
        android:id="@id/mcsdk_iam_space"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/mcsdk_iam_fs_content_padding_between"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mcsdk_iam_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@id/mcsdk_iam_media_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="mcsdk_iam_space,mcsdk_iam_media"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/mcsdk_iam_title"
        style="@style/McSdk.FullImageFill.Title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mcsdk_iam_body"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="This is the title"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@id/mcsdk_iam_content_barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="mcsdk_iam_title"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling"
        />

    <include
        layout="@layout/mcsdk_iam_fif_body_btns"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Provide a followup if you get this to work :)

Comment: Wow, that's actually pretty interesting! I did not know you could that with android layouts. Unfortunately, we also support iPhones and would have to find a similar solution for iOS :( -- I think this feature would add too much complexity in our codebase. Thank you for this fascinating answer though!